# Save mysql password in a bash script and use it instead of cmd line

Tags: mysql, bash

So , i'm writing an auto mysql database installer in bash.
I want to store the mysql password intro the bash script as a variable and use it directly.

Will create database.

mysqladmin -u root -p create account

```
PASSWD = "PASS"
mysqladmin -u root -p $PASSWD create account
```

How should i store corectly the password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put password with -p without space

`mysqladmin -u root -p$PASSWD create account`